# Package only binary compiled .so files of a python library compiled with Cython

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I have a package named `mypack` which inside has a module `mymod.py`, and 
the `__init__.py`.
For some reason that is not in debate, I need to package this module compiled 
(nor .py or .pyc files are allowed). That is, the `__init__.py` is the only
source file allowed in the distributed compressed file.

The folder structure is:

```
. 
│  
├── mypack
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── mymod.py
├── setup.py
```

I find that Cython is able to do this, by converting each .py file in a .so library
that can be directly imported with python.

The question is: how the `setup.py` file must be in order to allow an easy packaging and installation?

The target system has a virtualenv where the package must be installed with 
whatever method that allows easy install and uninstall (easy_install, pip, etc are all
welcome).

I tried all that was at my reach. I read `setuptools` and `distutils` documentation, 
all stackoverflow related questions,
and tried with  all kind of commands (sdist, bdist, bdist_egg, etc), with lots 
of combinations of setup.cfg and MANIFEST.in file entries.

The closest I got was with the below setup file, that would subclass the bdist_egg 
command in order to remove also .pyc files, but that is breaking the installation.

A solution that  installs "manually" the files in the venv is 
also good, provided that all ancillary files that are included in a proper
installation are covered (I need to run `pip freeze` in the venv and see
`mymod==0.0.1`).

Run it with:

```
python setup.py bdist_egg --exclude-source-files
```

and (try to) install it with

```
easy_install mymod-0.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
```

As you may notice, the target is linux 64 bits with python 2.7.

```
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from setuptools.command import bdist_egg
from setuptools.command.bdist_egg import  walk_egg, log 
import os

class my_bdist_egg(bdist_egg.bdist_egg):

    def zap_pyfiles(self):
        log.info("Removing .py files from temporary directory")
        for base, dirs, files in walk_egg(self.bdist_dir):
            for name in files:
                if not name.endswith('__init__.py'):
                    if name.endswith('.py') or name.endswith('.pyc'):
                        # original 'if' only has name.endswith('.py')
                        path = os.path.join(base, name)
                        log.info("Deleting %s",path)
                        os.unlink(path)

ext_modules=[
    Extension("mypack.mymod", ["mypack/mymod.py"]),
]

setup(
  name = 'mypack',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext, 
              'bdist_egg': my_bdist_egg },
  ext_modules = ext_modules,
  version='0.0.1',
  description='This is mypack compiled lib',
  author='Myself',
  packages=['mypack'],
)
```

UPDATE.
Following @Teyras answer, it was possible to build a wheel as requested in the answer. The `setup.py` file contents are:

```
import os
import shutil
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

class MyBuildExt(build_ext):
    def run(self):
        build_ext.run(self)
        build_dir = os.path.realpath(self.build_lib)
        root_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        target_dir = build_dir if not self.inplace else root_dir
        self.copy_file('mypack/__init__.py', root_dir, target_dir)

    def copy_file(self, path, source_dir, destination_dir):
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(source_dir, path)):
            shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source_dir, path), 
                            os.path.join(destination_dir, path))


setup(
  name = 'mypack',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': MyBuildExt},
  ext_modules = cythonize([Extension("mypack.*", ["mypack/*.py"])]),
  version='0.0.1',
  description='This is mypack compiled lib',
  author='Myself',
  packages=[],
  include_package_data=True )
```

The key point was to set `packages=[],`. The overwriting of the `build_ext` class `run` method was needed to get the `__init__.py` file inside the wheel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the answer suggesting setting `packages=[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45404570/2072269) is wrong and may break a lot of stuff, as can e.g. be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56024286/2650249). Don't use it. Instead of excluding all packages from the dist, you should exclude only the python files that will be cythonized and compiled to shared objects.

Below is a working example; it uses [my recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50517893/2650249) from the question [Exclude single source file from python bdist_egg or bdist_wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50506072/2650249). The example project contains package `spam` with two modules, `spam.eggs` and `spam.bacon`, and a subpackage `spam.fizz` with one module `spam.fizz.buzz`:

```
root
├── setup.py
└── spam
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── bacon.py
    ├── eggs.py
    └── fizz
        ├── __init__.py
        └── buzz.py
```

The module lookup is being done in the `build_py` command, so it is the one you need to subclass with custom behaviour.

#### Simple case: compile all source code, make no exceptions

If you are about to compile every `.py` file (including `__init__.py`s), it is already sufficient to override `build_py.build_packages` method, making it a noop. Because `build_packages` doesn't do anything, no `.py` file will be collected at all and the dist will include only cythonized extensions:

```
import fnmatch
from setuptools import find_packages, setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as build_py_orig
from Cython.Build import cythonize


extensions = [
    # example of extensions with regex
    Extension('spam.*', ['spam/*.py']),
    # example of extension with single source file
    Extension('spam.fizz.buzz', ['spam/fizz/buzz.py']),
]


class build_py(build_py_orig):
    def build_packages(self):
        pass


setup(
    name='...',
    version='...',
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
    cmdclass={'build_py': build_py},
)
```

#### Complex case: mix cythonized extensions with source modules

If you want to compile only selected modules and leave the rest untouched, you will need a bit more complex logic; in this case, you need to override module lookup. In the below example, I still compile `spam.bacon`, `spam.eggs` and `spam.fizz.buzz` to shared objects, but leave `__init__.py` files untouched, so they will be included as source modules:

```
import fnmatch
from setuptools import find_packages, setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as build_py_orig
from Cython.Build import cythonize


extensions = [
    Extension('spam.*', ['spam/*.py']),
    Extension('spam.fizz.buzz', ['spam/fizz/buzz.py']),
]
cython_excludes = ['**/__init__.py']


def not_cythonized(tup):
    (package, module, filepath) = tup
    return any(
        fnmatch.fnmatchcase(filepath, pat=pattern) for pattern in cython_excludes
    ) or not any(
        fnmatch.fnmatchcase(filepath, pat=pattern)
        for ext in extensions
        for pattern in ext.sources
    )


class build_py(build_py_orig):
    def find_modules(self):
        modules = super().find_modules()
        return list(filter(not_cythonized, modules))

    def find_package_modules(self, package, package_dir):
        modules = super().find_package_modules(package, package_dir)
        return list(filter(not_cythonized, modules))


setup(
    name='...',
    version='...',
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, exclude=cython_excludes),
    cmdclass={'build_py': build_py},
)
```

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer because it seems you know very well what you are saying. I'll try the code, though, and let you know whether or not it worked for me. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: Glad I could help! Ping me if should update the answer with an example code for your particular use case.

Comment: I cannot get this to work on Python 3.7.0. For one, build_py seems to return a filter object, so the filter() has to be wrapped in a list() call. Second, even though the filter result is correct for me, it has no effect on the package at all. The py files are still being included.

Comment: @hoefling I can confirm that the updated version works with 3.7.

Comment: @hoefling: i have tried your approach but it seems that the original c files are included in the wheel. is that expected?

Comment: @Matthijs it's a matter of Cython configuration. The C sources are written in-place by default, you can specify a custom target directory though. `cythonize(..., build_dir='/tmp')` etc.

Comment: great, will try and report back.

Comment: @hoefling: Thanks for this detailed answer. Really helps in getting majority of the stuff done. Could you also guide on how the following could be done as well?
1. Add some folders without .py code, eg: config folder (with .yml files), log folder (with .log files) etc. I tried adding to Extension (but realised only .py files are supported there), then I added to cython_excludes and that also didnt make sense since it excludes from the extension packages. 
2. Example on how to use the built wheel file. I tried importing into plain python terminal -leads to Import Error: Module not found issue

Comment: @N2M 1. non-pythonic files are included via the `package_data` keyword in `setup()`. Though the files should be located under a package that is included in distribution (=contained in the `packages` list). 2. The wheel must be installed first: `pip install path/to/mypkg.whl`

Comment: @hoefling: I have tried both. 
I have added my question in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67502034/python-wheel-package-build-and-install-with-cython-binary-so-files-only-and-con
Could you kindly refer and let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 9):

While packaging as a wheel is definitely what you want, the original question was about excluding *.py* source files from the package. This is addressed in [Using Cython to protect a Python codebase](https://bucharjan.cz/blog/using-cython-to-protect-a-python-codebase.html) by @Teyras, but his solution uses a hack: it removes the *packages* argument from the call to `setup()`. This prevents the *build_py* step from running which does, indeed, exclude the *.py* files but it also excludes any data files you want included in the package. (For example my package has a data file called VERSION which contains the package version number.) A better solution would be replacing the *build_py* setup command with a custom command which only copies the data files.

You also need the `__init__.py` file as described above.  So the custom *build_py* command should create the `__init_.py` file.  I found that the compiled `__init__.so` runs when the package is imported so all that is needed is an empty `__init__.py` file to tell Python that the directory is a module which is ok to import.

Your custom *build_py* class would look like:

```
import os
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py

class CustomBuildPyCommand(build_py):
    def run(self):
        # package data files but not .py files
        build_py.build_package_data(self)
        # create empty __init__.py in target dirs
        for pdir in self.packages:
            open(os.path.join(self.build_lib, pdir, '__init__.py'), 'a').close()
```

And configure *setup* to override the original *build_py* command:

```
setup(
   ...
   cmdclass={'build_py': CustomBuildPyCommand},
)
```

Comment: Great observation. I marked @Teyras answer though, because his answer meets the question requirements, and he answered first.

Comment: You sir, saved my day. I had no idea how to copy only the data files for a cythonized package. A small improvement, I copied the init.py files from a custom build_ext class instead of creating new ones, in case there is logic in them.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the wheel format (as suggested by fish2000). Then, in your `setup.py`, set the `packages` argument to `[]`. Your Cython extension will still build and the resulting .so files will be included in the resulting wheel package.

If your `__init__.py` is not included in the wheel, you can override the `run` method of `build_ext` class shipped by Cython and copy the file from your source tree to the build folder (the path can be found in `self.build_lib`).

Comment: It works!! I will update the answer with the setup.py for self-contention.

Answer (score 1):

This was exactly the sort of problem [**the Python wheels format**](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/27/python-on-wheels/) – [described in PEP 427](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) – was developed to address.

Wheels are a replacement for Python eggs (which were/are problematic for a bunch of reasons) – [they are supported by `pip`](https://packaging.python.org/installing/), can contain architecture-specific private binaries (here is [one example of such an arrangement](https://github.com/lepture/python-wheels/blob/master/.travis.yml)) and are accepted generally by the Python communities who have stakes in these kind of things.

Here is one `setup.py` snippet from the [aforelinked](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/27/python-on-wheels/) *Python on Wheels* article, showing how one sets up a binary distribution:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.dist import Distribution

class BinaryDistribution(Distribution):
    def is_pure(self):
        return False

setup(
    ...,
    include_package_data=True,
    distclass=BinaryDistribution,
)
```

… in leu of the older (but probably somehow still canonically supported) `setuptools` classes you are using. It’s very straightforward to make Wheels for your distribution purposes, as outlined – as I recall from experience, either the `wheel` modules’ build process is somewhat cognizant of `virtualenv`, or it’s very easy to use one within the other.

In any case, trading in the `setuptools` egg-based APIs for wheel-based tooling should save you some serious pain, I should think.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I still can't make it work. Followed your advice but the .py and .pyc files are still included in the wheel. And can't find either how to remove files subclassing (or whatever is needed) the Distribution class. I read all the links and noting. About the example you quote, I don't know how to translate that yaml configuration file to a python setup.py script. ¿Could you provide more specifics? Thanks!

Comment: @eguaio you should have a look at **Delocate** – https://github.com/matthew-brett/delocate – the source of which has a great many useful functions for manipulating wheels and shared object files. That will likely get you going… as for the yaml thing, I would predict that that’s going to be the hard/irritating part of the project, where you’ll just have to dive in and write your own configuration-file reader code, hewn closely to the intrinsic form taken by the data you work with. Indeed!

Comment: I searched in the indicated links and I still can find a solution. In those links, a lot of tunning is done over the Distribution, run_setup, setup, etc classes, functions and modules. I tried to navigated the source files of many of the libraries with the bdist_wheel command and the source is still distributed.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I'm afraid you only provided pointers to a solution, but we are still lacking a complete self-contained solution to the small simple case I posted. I was not able to use your pointers to get a solution, and that is why I didn't mark your answer as correct.