# Cython: control cythonize to stop placing compiled `.c` file from `.pyx` file in install directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, cythonize

I have  a small helper function `test` containing sensitive code. To mask this code, I have written the function in `hello.pyx` and using it in my package `mypackage`.

I am able to build and use it by modifying the `setup.py` for the package to something like below:

```
import os                                                                                                                                             
from setuptools import setup, find_packages                                                                                                           
from Cython.Build import cythonize                                                                                                                    
os.chdir(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir)))                                                                        

setup(                                                                                                                                                
    name='mypackage',                                                                                                                                  
    ext_modules = cythonize('mypackage/hello.pyx'),                                                                                             
    packages=find_packages(),                                                                                                                         
    include_package_data=True,                                                                                                                        
    )
```

However, when i build/install it via `python setup.py` or `pip install`, the cython generated `hello.c` as well as `hello.so` are getting placed in the install directory (in my case `~/.local/python2.7/site-packages/mypackage/`)

I can manually remove the `hello.c` from the install directory (leaving just the `hello.so` file) and the package runs fine.

Is there a way I can automate this process so that i don't need to manually remove the compiled `c` file ?

I looked at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499453/package-only-binary-compiled-so-files-of-a-python-library-compiled-with-cython). However, I am getting an error during cythonize operation when i am trying to build the wheel using `pip wheel .` . Also, in my case I am fine with installing using tar.gz as long as the installed code doesn't contain plain text files for `hello.c`

[Edit]

I was able to stop placing a `.c` file in the install directory by using `include_package_data=False` in my `setup.py`.. However, am not exactly sure whether this option means for non python files in the project

Comment: Do you have `MANIFEST.in` in your project directory? If yes, what does it contain?

Comment: There is no `MANIFEST.in`.. btw just updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How do you intend to distribute the package?

WIthout the `.c` files in the source distributable, Cython becomes a dependency for your project. As Cython is a static code generator, it is not required *after* the `.c` files are generated.

By including them in your source distribution, the package can be installed without needing to have Cython by using standard setuptools extensions on the `.c` files rather than using cythonize on the `.pyx` files.

This is also the recommendation in [Cython documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html?highlight=distributing#distributing-cython-modules) which shows how to switch between the two for development and distributing.

If you really want to exclude them and make Cython a dependency, add the following to MANIFEST.in

`exclude mypackage/*.c`

Comment: I am ok with Cython being a dependency. Thanks this works