# Using the same setup.py for developing and installing a non-cythonized as well as a cythonized package?

Tags: python, pip, cython, setuptools, cythonize

Given is a (set of) Python3 packages that is to be deployed in different scenarios either cythonized or as original scripts; the source are pure Python3 sources. Preferably, I would like to use the same `setup.py`, if possible.

| use case | in-place | include .py modules | cythonized .so modules |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. development `pip3 install -e .` | yes | yes |  |
| 2. "unoptimized" install `pip3 install .` |  | yes |  |
| 3. cythonized install `pip3 install . --install-option="cythonize"` |  | no (except `__init__.py`) | yes |
| 4. build (binary) wheel `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` |  | no (except `__init__.py`) | yes |

So far, I succeeded in *building* a binary distribution wheel with only the cythonized .so shared library and without the original .py module files, following [Package only binary compiled .so files of a python library compiled with Cython](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043918)
. This covers use case #4 and is handled by class `build_py`.

However, I would also cover #1, #2 and maybe #3; #3 might be better tackled by separately building the bdist_wheel and then installing this, of not otherwise possible in a single step.

```py
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043918
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as build_py_orig
try:
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
except:
    cythonize = None

from setuptools.command.install import install as install_orig

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/56043918
extensions = [
    Extension('spam.*', ['spam/**/*.py'],
              extra_compile_args=["-O3", "-Wall"]),
]

cython_excludes = ['spam/**/__init__.py']

def not_cythonized(tup):
    (package, module, filepath) = tup
    return any(
        fnmatch.fnmatchcase(filepath, pat=pattern) for pattern in cython_excludes
    ) or not any(
        fnmatch.fnmatchcase(filepath, pat=pattern)
        for ext in extensions
        for pattern in ext.sources
    )


class build_py(build_py_orig):
    def find_modules(self):
        modules = super().find_modules()
        return list(filter(not_cythonized, modules))

    def find_package_modules(self, package, package_dir):
        modules = super().find_package_modules(package, package_dir)
        return list(filter(not_cythonized, modules))


class install(install_orig):
    def finalize_options(self):
        super().finalize_options()
        self.distribution.ext_modules = None

setup(
    name='spam',
    packages=find_packages(),
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        extensions,
        exclude=cython_excludes,
        compiler_directives={
            "language_level": 3,
            "always_allow_keywords": True,
        },
        build_dir="build",  # needs to be explicitly set, otherwise pollutes package sources
    ) if cythonize is not None else [],
    cmdclass={
        'build_py': build_py,
        'install': install,
    },
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[...]
)
```

The problems I'm facing here:

1. for use cases #1 and #2 I don't want to cythonize, so `ext_modules=` should not be specified/set.

   1. What is a sensible way to handle `ext_modules=` in this situation? I find it hard to detect the requested operation (`install`, `install -e`, `develop`) **before** calling `setup()`, so would it be better to inherit and override the `install` and `develop` classes?
   2. If the latter, is it possible and allowed to clear the `ext_modules` and how do I avoid prematurely evaluating `cythonize(...)`?
2. in use case #2 with the above code pip3 decides to build an egg which unfortunately includes the `.so`'s. Might this be due to `cythonize(...)` getting evaluated in any case? can I avoid building the egg or how do I prevent the egg build process from including the shared libs?
3. this currently includes both the sources (which I don't want to be include) as well as the cythonized modules: how can I prevent the `install` class from installing most of the source modules, yet installing the `__init__.py`s?